# DBeaver does not let me edit table and data

Tags: dbeaver

I am not sure if it is a bug with the new version, but I cannot edit data on tables and the related menus are disabled. I have not changed and settings and tried to find a solution on web on on the app menus, but still no solution. Any idea?

[image: DBevaver]

Comment: 'I am not sure if it is a bug with the new version'- it worked in an older version on the same table?

Comment: Yes, but not sure if it started with the last updates. Maybe there is a setting that changed unconciously.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Any idea about this?